# Parse JSON Data with PHP

Tags: php, foreach, json

I have parsed JSON data numerous times but for some reason cannot find the correct syntax to use when the data is nested. I am trying to parse the "assets" from this JSON but continue to get a invalid argument supplied foreach() regardless of what I try.

```
   "3435":{
      "name":"COLO-1014-SJ1",
      "nickname":"US-SJC-004",
      "type":"Colocated Server",
      "location":"San Jose:55 S Market",
      "assets":{
         "CPU":[
            {
               "model":"Intel E3 1270"
            }
         ],
         "Hard Drives":[
            {
               "model":"Western Digital 500GB RE4 ABYX SATA"
            },
            {
               "model":"Western Digital 500GB RE4 ABYX SATA"
            },
            {
               "model":"Kingston 240GB SSD"
            }
         ],
         "RAM":[
            {
               "model":"Super Talent 4GB DDR3 1333 ECC"
            },
            {
               "model":"Super Talent 4GB DDR3 1333 ECC"
            },
            {
               "model":"Super Talent 4GB DDR3 1333 ECC"
            },
            {
               "model":"Super Talent 4GB DDR3 1333 ECC"
            }
         ],
```

I would expect it to be something along the lines of...

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach ($json as $item)
{
    foreach ($item['assets']->RAM as $asset)
    {
        echo $asset->model;
    }
```

Comment: 2nd json_decode arg is for assoc array, but you'r using a mix between array and object in your loop. With true as 2nd arg please use $item['assets']['RAM'] or use object like many below answer with false as 2nd arg

Comment: That was it, thank you so much. I tried all of the solutions below and none worked until I noticed this. If you would like to respond, I will accept answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From php official documentation: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

The 2nd func arg is for assoc array return. You can use it if you prefer to manipulate assoc array over object.

But you actually mix array and object in your loop.

If you keep the arg at `TRUE`, please use `$item['assets']['RAM']`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have forgot to add the surrounding curly braces around the JSON data. If your JSON data is invalid then the json_decode() function will not work correctly.

I have fixed your JSON code below and this now validates and meets the JSON standard.

```
{
    "3435": {
        "name": "COLO-1014-SJ1",
        "nickname": "US-SJC-004",
        "type": "Colocated Server",
        "location": "San Jose:55 S Market",
        "assets": {
            "CPU": [
                {
                    "model": "Intel E3 1270"
                }
            ],
            "Hard Drives": [
                {
                    "model": "Western Digital 500GB RE4 ABYX SATA"
                },
                {
                    "model": "Western Digital 500GB RE4 ABYX SATA"
                },
                {
                    "model": "Kingston 240GB SSD"
                }
            ],
            "RAM": [
                {
                    "model": "Super Talent 4GB DDR3 1333 ECC"
                },
                {
                    "model": "Super Talent 4GB DDR3 1333 ECC"
                },
                {
                    "model": "Super Talent 4GB DDR3 1333 ECC"
                },
                {
                    "model": "Super Talent 4GB DDR3 1333 ECC"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you ever need to check your JSON code you can use a validator such as http://jsonlint.com/

Secondly, your PHP code is also wrong:

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach ($json as $item)
{
    foreach ($item->assets->RAM as $asset)
    {
        echo $asset->model;
    }
}
```

You have been trying to access the returned object as an array which will also cause issues with the foreach loop.

Comment: My JSON was valid at that link, but that was my fault for just posting a small snippet of it. I pasted your PHP code exactly though and it continues to spam Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for each loop.

Comment: Actually not all elements in my JSON have an "assets" array. I think this may be the problem. Is there any way to check if it exists before doing a foreach loop over it?

Comment: @BrettPowell You could try something like if(!empty($item->assets)){ // add code }

Answer (score 2):

`$item->assets`, not `$item['assets']`. Do a `print_r($json)` so you can see the types of the various parts of the JSON - it'll make them easier to figure out how to access them.

Answer (score 0):

It is parsed as an object, so:

```
foreach ($item -> assets -> RAM as $asset){ ... }
```